# SICP: Why does this recursion-based sine approximation work?

Tags: recursion, trigonometry, sicp

[Here](http://jots-jottings.blogspot.com/2011/09/sicp-115-sines-of-fathers.html) is the question and solution to *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*' exercise 1.15 ([see here](https://sarabander.github.io/sicp/html/1_002e2.xhtml#g_t1_002e2_002e3)). My problem is, I don't know how the combination of these formulae actually work:

[image]

and

[image]

for small `x` radian values.

I understand the idea that the closer the radian angle gets to zero, the more it approximates the sine of that angle. I've seen excellent explanations (MIT OCW, Khan Academy). I also have worked out how the

[image]

formula is derived. But how are they being used together to derive an answer to `sin(x)`? The `p` function seems to simply be taking the variable angle divided by `3` each recursive pass until `angle` is down below `0.1` Then on the way back, we perform `p` as many times as we had to divide by `3`. So it seems

[image]

magically becomes the same as

[image]

through recursive application. How? I'm not very deeply versed in recursion theory. Also, if this is logarithmically getting closer to `0.1`, it's not as if we're totaling up lots of small `x`'s a la integration. This seems to be doing something vaguely like the Y-combinator -- which I also don't grasp that well yet.

Also, when we see the recursive steps (recursion) repeatedly dividing `angle` by $3$, what tells you definitively this is logarithmic? I mean, it looks like it's taking those giant order of magnitude leaps at each division, but is there another analytical way to call this logarithmic reduction?

Comment: "order of magnitude leap" = logarithmic. The logarithm counts the number of orders of magnitude.

Comment: It magically becomes `sin(x)=3*sin(x/3)-4*sin(x/3)^3=3*x/3-4*(x/3)^3 =x-4/27x^3`

Comment: As for "how it works" - you already showed how it works. You proved the trigonometric identity, and you confirmed the approximation for small `x`. This is just recursion: Take a hard problem and convert to a simpler problem. Repeat until the problem is so simple you can solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to point out is that [image] is not exactly accurate since x is just an approximation. The correct notation is
[image]. This might seem a little nitpicky but it's important because this explains the exercise and the definition of sine given in the book.

The way [image: sin(x) = 3sin(x/3) - 4sin^3(x/3)] and [image] are combined is in the definition of the sine procedure. The idea is that we would like to return either the approximation or the second formula ([image: sin(x) = 3sin(x/3) - 4sin^3(x/3)]) depending on the value of x.

If x is "sufficiently small", then we just return x as an approximation for sin(x). But if it's not "sufficiently small" we will use [image: sin(x) = 3sin(x/3) - 4sin^3(x/3)]. This is obviously fine since it's an equality. It might seem unnecessary until you notice that sin(x/3) is smaller and therefore it *might* be "sufficiently smaller". This is why the procedure is recursive, we will keep doing this until the argument for sine is "sufficiently small".

It seems that the source of your confusion is here:

> So it seems [image] magically becomes the same as [image].

This is not the case. It's a bit tricky since `(define (p x) (- (* 3 x) (* (4 (cube x))))` doesn't include any sine but remember that the x in this definition is just a local variable. But if we look at the final line of the definition of the sine procedure we can see that we are actually calling `(p (sin (/ angle 3.0)))))` so the sine is in the argument of the `p` call.

The reason why the recursion is logarithmic in terms of the number of steps is that the number of times we will be calling the `p` procedure is around the number of times we have to divide the angle by 3.0 to get a value smaller than 0.1. This is a value close to 1 if the angle is a big number. So we will have to call `p`  until angle/(3.0^n) < 0.1 which approximates to the n such that 3.0^n > angle which approximates to [image]